# Make Xamarin Forms default to compile all XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I create a `ContentPage` in Xamarin Forms, the code behind partial class gets decorated with an `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` attribute. I know I can add an assembly level attribute for this, but is there any way to prevent the page level attribute being used besides explicitly removing it?

Say I decided to `Skip` most pages instead, I will have to go and change that attribute on every `ContentPage`.

**PS:** I have suggested this on [Xamarin Customer Feedback](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/258559-xamarin-forms-suggestions/suggestions/32145613-make-xamarin-forms-default-to-not-compile-all-xa). If this interests you, please check it out and give it a vote.

Answer (score 2):

You should suggest this on the xamarin uservoice site and post a comment with a link to the suggestion so others can vote on it.

https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions

Comment: Great idea. I have done so thanks, and will accept if nobody can give me an answer not depending on an updated Xamarin Forms.